# Overlay container should close on click but not if a anchor or input child is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay

probably rather simple, but can't find a proper solution:

```
    <!-- newsletter -->
    <div id="newsletter-overlay" class="blur-overlay">
      <button type="button" class="close-btn">x</button>
      <div class="inner-wrap"> 
        <!-- Newsletter Form -->
        <div id="newsletter-form">
          <form action="/newsletter" method="post" class="group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button2" value="Signup">
            <div class="messages"> <span class="error-message">Please enter a valid E-Mail Address.</span> <span class="success-message">Thank you for your signup.</span> </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /Newsletter Form --> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /newsletter -->
```

and my JS looks like this …

```
    $('.blur-overlay').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked')
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.blur-overlay').fadeOut(150);
    });
```

The overlay is `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%` and lies on top of everything. I want the overlay to close once it is clicked, but don't want that to happen if a `a` or an `input` inside the overlay is clicked.

I thought of something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
    $('.blur-overlay *').not('input, a').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked')
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.blur-overlay').fadeOut(150);
    });
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This should work : `$('.blur-overlay *:not('input, a').on` ...

Comment: @Zl3n no does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.blur-overlay').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked')

// check if click was on the overlay and not on its children
    if (e.target == this) {
    $('.blur-overlay').fadeOut(150);
}
});
```

Comment: Don't have access to pc, answering from phone. Sorry for brief answer.